# Light blue color from WinUser.h

Tags: mfc

I need to implement a MouseOver effect on some listbox items and I need to use a light blue as the highlight color.

Does anyone know from the `winuser.h` file what constant is the light blue color ? I tested over 20 of them, cannot find the correct one, maybe someone here knows.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like Deep Sky Blue, Dodger Blue...

Comment: But you keep saying "the" light blue, as in there's some specific light blue you want to use.

Comment: I don't want a specific type, any light blue will be okay.

Comment: You know those constants are meant to be used with `::GetSysColor()`, dont you? They're not proper color constants

Comment: Yeah, I am using them with ::GetSysColor(), I thought one of them could be a light blue, just as when you hover the mouse over a combobox, the combobox turns into a light blue, that color I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a specific "light blue", open Paint, or any other program that handles colors, and move the color sliders until you get the RGB values you need. Then do:

```
COLORREF myLightBlue = RGB(R, G, B);
```

I think you'll find you need a high B value, to make it blue, and quite high R and B values, to make it light. For example, you can try RGB(200, 230, 255);

Anyway, it would probably be advisable to use some system color, taken with `::GetSysColor()`

**EDIT:**
If you are using visual styles, I think you have to use [GetThemeColor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649930.aspx) to get the color defined by the current theme. Ive never used it myself, so I cannot help with that.

Comment: I already try that, I taken some codes, for example, this one: http://www.computerhope.com/cgi-bin/htmlcolor.pl?c=31AFF5 but all codes make my highlight color black...

Comment: I would say that if you are using RGB(49, 175, 245) and getting black, maybe you are doing something wrong? You should post the code you are using, plus information on the environment (Windows version, using visual styles or not) and with that maybe you'll get better answers

Comment: I am doing COLOREF lightBlue = RGB(49, 175, 245); COLOREF x = ::GetSysColor(lighBlue); I am using Windows 7 x64 and visual studio 2008

Comment: That's not the way it works. You pass GetSysColor one of the predefined constants, which tells which color you want (e.g. the color of the button face; the color of the tooltip text; ...) and it returns the COLORREF with that color. For example: COLORREF col = GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT); gives you the color of items selected in a control. Check the docs on GetSysColor [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx)